# recursive feature elimination with caret: Metric 'ROC' is not created by the summary function

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

I'd appreciate some help getting started with recursive feature elimination using the `caret` package. I have 74 features with values that fall between 0 and 1, and a classification variable that takes the value of 0 or 1.

```
# get data (N=37)
  library(RCurl)
  x <-
 getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ericpgreen/46865e44182441332597aff1d5fcae86/raw/005774dfd035cdb357765415ded521c25f884d5f/rfe-example.csv")
  df <- read.csv(text = x)
  df <- df[, -1]
```

I'd like to find the best subset of items that predict the classification. My metric of choice is ROC.

```
set.seed(1)

control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, 
                      method = "LOOCV",
                      repeats = 5, 
                      number = 10,
                      returnResamp="final", 
                      verbose = TRUE)

 trainctrl <- trainControl(classProbs = TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
 rfe.ff.cg <- rfe(df[, 2:length(df)],         # features
                  df[, 1],                    # classification
                  sizes = 2:(length(df)-1),   # all possible subsets
                  rfeControl = control,
                  method = "svmRadial",
                  metric = "ROC",
                  trControl = trainctrl)
```

It seems like a subset of 3 features is best:

```
predictors(result)
#[1] "v24" "v58" "v2"
```

But I'm getting two types of errors:

> Metric 'ROC' is not created by the summary function; 'RMSE' will be used instead

and

> The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?

Is there a different parameter to allow the features I have? Features v1:v69 were originally on a 0-9 scale and I rescaled to be 0-1. Features v70-v74 were originally on a 0-3 scale and I rescaled to be 0-1. Some features only have 2 or 3 unique values, as indicated by the warning.

```
table(df$v5)
#0.888888888888889                 1 
#                4                33
```

Comment: adding `rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary` seems to take care of the first error message, but I now have an error: `replacement has 0 rows, data has 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROC is not included in the default summary, so needed to add `rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary`.

Ran without error after converting the classification variable to a factor: `df$class <- factor(df$class)`.